# Linq one to many with filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have an Entity Framework database that I'm querying, so I'm using linq-to-entities.

Here's my query:

// 'Find' is just a wrapper method that returns IQueryable

```
var q = r.Find(topic =>
    topic.PageId != null &&
    !topic.Page.IsDeleted &&
    topic.Page.IsActive)
```

// These are standard EF extension methods, which are used to include
linked tables. **Note: Page_Topic has a one-to-many relationship with topic**.

```
.Include(topic => topic.Page.Route)
.Include(topic => topic.Page_Topic.Select(pt => pt.Page.Route))
```

// HERE'S THE QUESTION: This select statement needs to flatten `Page_Topic` (which it does). But it seems to do it in the wrong place. To explain, if I were to include another column that depended on Page_Topic (for example: 'PillarRoutName2', I'd have to apply the same flattening logic to that column too. Surely the filtering of `Page_Topic` should be done higher up the query in a DRY way.

```
.Select(x => new
{
    TopicName = x.Name,
    HubRouteName = x.Page.Route.Name,
    PillarRouteName = x.Page_Topic.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsPrimary).Page.Route.Name
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely the filtering of Page_Topic should be done higher up the query in a DRY way.

Correct! And it's easy to do this:

```cs
.Select(x => new
{
    TopicName = x.Name,
    HubRouteName = x.Page.Route.Name,
    FirstTopic = x.Page_Topic.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsPrimary)
})
.Select(x => new
{
    TopicName = x.TopicName,
    HubRouteName = x.HubRouteName,
    PillarRouteName = x.FirstTopic.Page.Route.Name,
    PillarRoutName2 = x.FirstTopic. ...
}).ToList();
```

Depending on where you start to get properties from `FirstTopic` you can also use `x.Page_Topic.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IsPrimary).Page` or `.Page.Route` in the first part.

Note that you don't need the `Include`s. They will be ignored because the query is a projection (`Select(x => new ...`).

Comment: So, this query do not produce duplicate JOINs with `ROW_NUMBER` ?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Sorry, I don't understand the question. As far as I can see, the output is as expected.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It's EF6 classic, it generates a query with one `OUTER APPLY` and `TOP(1)`